# How to resize subview subview based on autolayout?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nsview

I am having a NSView let call this **Detail View** in my main view controller in which all the auto layout constraints will be added in dependent with the main view. I will be adding a subview lets call this **sub detail** to this **Detail View** based on user input. This sub detail view contains lot of view for which constraints are added in accordance with the **sub detail** view. While adding the **sub detail** to **Detail View** as sub view I am setting the frame by getting the frame of **Detail View** and setting x = 0 and y = 0;. My problem is that when a user maximise the window and user select and I am adding the **sub detail** view to **Detail View** the size of **sub detail** subview remains the same but **sub detail** view get auto resized as per required. Could any one guide me what i am doing wrong. Below i am sharing you the code where in which i am adding the subview and output view in the link 
[image]
I don't want the blank blue space.

```
NSRect f = detailView.frame;
f.origin.x = 0;
f.origin.y = 0;
ConfigLogin *subDetail = [[ConfigLogin alloc] initWithFrame:f];
[subDetail setWantsLayer:YES];
[subDetail setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable|NSViewHeightSizable];
[subDetail setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];
subDetail.layer.backgroundColor = [NSColor blueColor].CGColor;
subDetail.frame = f;
[detailView addSubview:detailView];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could find the answer as while adding the subview we are not adding the constraints to make the view fit to the super view.

```
  +(void) fitSubViewToSuperView:(NSView *) subview superView:(NSView *) superView
  {
NSLayoutConstraint *width    = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                constraintWithItem:subview
                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                relatedBy:0
                                toItem:superView
                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                multiplier:1.0
                                constant:0];

NSLayoutConstraint *height   = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                constraintWithItem:subview
                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                relatedBy:0
                                toItem:superView
                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                multiplier:1.0
                                constant:0];

NSLayoutConstraint *top      = [NSLayoutConstraint
                               constraintWithItem:subview
                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                               toItem:superView
                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                               multiplier:1.0f
                               constant:0.f];

NSLayoutConstraint *leading = [NSLayoutConstraint
                               constraintWithItem:subview
                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                               toItem:superView
                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                               multiplier:1.0f
                               constant:0.f];
[superView addConstraint:width];
[superView addConstraint:height];
[superView addConstraint:top];
[superView addConstraint:leading];
}
```